# Can't understand why this small segment of code won't work

Tags: java, arrays, runtime-error

```
    int[] binArray = new int[100];
    int bins = 10; 
    int numOfIterations = 100/bins;
    int binElement = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<numOfIterations; i++) {
        binElement = binElement + bins;
        binElement = binArray[i];
        System.out.println(binArray[i]);
    }
```

Keeps printing:
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0

Trying to print: 0, 10, 20, 30, 40 ,50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100

Comment: You have never give a value to any position in the array. They are 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your problem is a misunderstanding of how to assign a value to an array**

```
/* Commented below is your code with comments of what the code is doing */
//sets bin element to 10.
binElement = binElement + bins;
// binArray[i] is zero (by default), so all you do is set binElement back to zero.
binElement = binArray[i];
// You still have not updated the array so it prints the default int array value of zero.
System.out.println(binArray[i]);
```

Change your code to the code posted below which correctly assigns values to an array, and your problems are solved :)

```
int[] binArray = new int[100];
int bins = 10; 
int numOfIterations = 100/bins;
int binElement = 0;
for (int i=0; i<numOfIterations; i++) {
    binElement = binElement + bins;
    binArray[i] = binElement ;
    System.out.println(binArray[i]);
}
```

Take a look at the link posted below for plenty of examples on how to assign values to an array.

[Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Answer (score 2):

Because binArray is initialized to 0, and you are never writing anything to it.

Flip this line:   `binElement = binArray[i];` to say this: `binArray[i] = binElement;` and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign values to elements of `binArray`. Do this within the `for` loop:

```
binElement[i] = binElement;
```

not this

```
binElement = binElement[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `binElement = binElement[i]` to `binElement[i] = binElement;` Also change the `bins` value to 0. Then only it will print `0,10..` like this. Otherwise it will print `10,20,...` like this.

```
int[] binArray = new int[100];
int bins = 10; 
int numOfIterations = 100/bins;
int binElement = 0;
bins = 0;  // To print from 0
for (int i=0; i<numOfIterations; i++) {
    binElement = binElement + bins;
    binArray[i] = binElement ;
    System.out.println(binArray[i]);
}
```